# First steps Django errors

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pydev

I need to ask because I'm starting in Django and it was impossible for me to continue with the tutorial that I'm following. I've just completed a Python course, I know the basics of python. The case is that I've installed Django in my mac and it's OK because when I do in the IDLE the

```
import django
print django.VERSION
```

It makes a good answer without errors in IDLE (is the software that I use to write python code). But when I execute in the Terminal the command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

It raises this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 69, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.servers.basehttp import AdminMediaHandler, run, WSGIServerException, get_internal_wsgi_application
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 26, in <module>
    from django.views import static
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/static.py", line 95, in <module>
    template_translatable = ugettext_noop(u"Index of %(directory)s")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 75, in gettext_noop
    return _trans.gettext_noop(message)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    if settings.USE_I18N:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

I also want to ask you some questions:

- Can I use XAMPP instead of Django? How?
- What is Django used for exactly?
- I've installed PyDev in Eclipse. How can I set Django to execute code properly?

Comment: Looks like you do not have a django settings.py. Did you use django-admin.py startproject? Django is a web framework it looks after the low level stuff of creating a website

Answer (score 0):

call command `django-admin startproject xxx` under the target directory. You can get three .py files: **setting.py**, **urls.py** and **manage.py**. And you can execute `python manage.py runserver` command

Answer (score 0):

I think it's slightly outdated now, but I'd seriously recommend going through the [Djangobook](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html) examples.  It'll explain how to set up Django properly, and give a pretty good foundation in how to use it.